# Can i use vector drawable file in ActionBar Menu Icon?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-vectordrawable

Can i use vector file in ActionBar Menu Icon ?

Now appCompat supports vector file from API > 8. Can i use vector drawable in ActionBar Menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me. Vector drawable fine for actionbar

Comment: Can you share how you did for Android < 21 ?  tint/fillcolor do not work for me

Comment: This is how I managed to get it working, making sure that this is called before showing the vector drawable `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 6):

If you set menu icon programmatically, it works for Android < 21.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        MenuItem cancelMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);

        VectorDrawableCompat vectorDrawableCompat = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.vector_drawable_delete, null);
        cancelMenuItem.setIcon(vectorDrawableCompat);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` either in Application or in Activity.

Comment: You can do so in your gradle.build, too. Just add the line `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` within the `android{ }` tag. See [ClickMe](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-working-svg-vector-drawables/) for more info.

Comment: Using `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` doesn't work for me, though i'm using gradle plugin 3.0.1, but `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` works perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

in your xml file use ->

```
`app:icon="@drawable/vector_name_available"``
```

instead of the pre android xml suggested

```
android:icon="@drawable/????????????
```